# @Transactional continues at exception handling

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I am facing some strange issue..

Let's say:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void do() {
   try {
      Float x = 200;
      Float y = 100;

      TestObject x = new TestObject(x, y);
      x.setX(50);

      if (x.getX() > x.getY())
         testService.save(x);
      else
         throw new Exception("ERROR");
   } 
   catch (Exception e) {
      errorsService.save(e);
   }
}
```

Both `save` methods are marked as `@Transactional`.

Problem: As soon as code throws an exception - `errorsService.save(e);` makes a commit - add `50` as a x value of `TestObject`. I tried to declare `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` - no success. Always commit, without rollback!

In all other methods there is no any issue with transactions - everything works perfect!

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception? Where is it thrown?

Comment: I do it manually, that's the problem I suppose

Comment: Why don't you answer the question?

Comment: @JBNizet Please take a look at the code.. It throws error manually. Anyway, there is no any stack trace, because I need it only for sign - if exception thrown then I have to handle it in separate way

Answer (score 2):

For a transaction to roll back, the Exception needs to be thrown from inside the @Transactional method, which doesn't happen in your case.

Comment: It seems to be.. Can you tell how can I implement it? Basically I did it with boolean flag but with exception it looks nicer))

Comment: @nKognito why do you call save() in the catch block if you intend it to rollback, and thus not do anything? Just remove the else block and the catch block, and you'll have what you want: nothing will happen if `x.getX() <= x.getY()`.

Comment: I heed to save exception in the database, that's why I do it)